# merge multiple table to CSV powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, merge, formattable

Hi there are two tables below

```
Computer A
------------
20.03
20.02
20.01
```

```
Computer B
------------
20.03
20.02
20.01
XXX
XXX
```

Hi I have a question is I want to merge into a CSV,so I need to achieve first below as :

```
Computer A      Computer B
------------    ------------
20.03           20.03
20.02           20.02
20.01           20.01  
                XXX
                XXX
```

How can I do?  I have many something like those tables that need to merge
I tried some many time, just can't be able to do that

Comment: are the tables literal text tables or are they some sort of object? if they are just text, are they individual multiline strings OR are they an array of single line strings?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey They are the PSCustomObject I think.     $str is ComputerA                                                       $str |Select-Object @{Label='ComputerA';Expression={$_.ComputerA}},@{Label='ComputerB';Expression={ ?? }}         ?? is I don't know how to do

Comment: @Dukeyu - please, add the _very important_ info to your Question. those are not tables ... they are PSCOs and the display is entirely wrong for dealing with the actual object.

Answer (score 0):

Start by turning both arrays into hashtables - this way we can quickly lookup whether a value exists in one or both:

```
$ComputerATable = @{}
$AObjects |ForEach-Object { $ComputerATable[$_.'Computer A'] = $_ }

$ComputerBTable = @{}
$AObjects |ForEach-Object { $ComputerATable[$_.'Computer B'] = $_ }
```

Now we just need to loop through all *distinct* computer names to build our "merged table":

```bsh
$merged = $ComputerATable.Keys,$ComputerBTable.Keys |Sort-Object |ForEach-Object {
  # Create a new object with the value (if present) from either table
  [pscustomobject]@{
    'Computer A' = if($ComputerATable.ContainsKey($_)){ $_ }
    'Computer B' = if($ComputerBTable.ContainsKey($_)){ $_ }
  }
}
```